# Error in mysql trigger and update

Tags: mysql, variables, if-statement, triggers

I have the next trigger:

```
CREATE
    TRIGGER t_call_status 
    AFTER INSERT 
    ON tblcdr FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    
    DECLARE lastid integer;
    DECLARE nseg integer;
    
    SET lastid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    SET nseg = 120;

    IF ((origen = 'ANSWERED' && destino = 'ANSWERED') && (billsec_origen >= nseg && disposition_destino >= nseg)) THEN
        update tblcdr set call_status = 3 where id = lastid;
    ELSE IF (origen = 'ANSWERED' && destino = 'ANSWERED') THEN
        update tblcdr set call_status = 2 where id = lastid;
    ELSE IF (origen = 'ANSWERED' && destino <> 'ANSWERED') THEN
        update tblcdr set call_status = 1 where id = lastid;
    ELSE IF (origen <> 'ANSWERED' && destino <> 'ANSWERED') THEN
        update tblcdr set call_status = 0 where id = lastid;
    ELSE
        update tblcdr set call_status = 0 where id = lastid;
    END IF;

END;
```

But, i got the next error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '' at line 7

How can I fix it?

Greetings.

Comment: first problem is, you can't update the same table the trigger runs on in an after insert trigger. you need to modify the data before it is inserted with a before insert trigger. that isn't causing your syntax error but it's going to crop up pretty soon

Comment: What MySQL client are you using? Most would require you to set a statement delimiter to end the trigger creation following `END`, though the method to do that varies.

Comment: I am using phpmyadmin.

Comment: pala_ you right, Icannot change a table while the INSERT trigger is firing. The INSERT might do some locking which could result in a deadlock. Also, updating the table from a trigger would then cause the same trigger to fire again in an infinite recursive loop. Both of these reasons are why MySQL prevents you from doing this.